# Можно ли и как изменить фигуру Button в libgdx?

Tags: button, libgdx

Можно ли изменить фигуру кнопки с прямоугольника на многоугольник , пишу(пытаюсь по крайней мере) игру с тактической битвой и мне очень удобно наследовать класс Button
из за обработчика событий , но хождение по квадратикам выглядит уж очень не красиво
и хочется сделать поле боя на подобия героев меча и магии

Answer (score 0):

немного изменение в вопросе куда вот это

```
void createHexagon(){
    pos = new Vector2(nullx,nully);
    bottom = new Vector2(pos.x + getWidth() / 2, pos.y); //точка нижнего угла
    bottomright = new Vector2(pos.x + getWidth(), pos.y + getHeight() * .25f);//точка нижне-правого угла
    topright = new Vector2(pos.x + getWidth(), pos.y + getHeight() * .75f);//точка верхне-правого угла
    top = new Vector2(pos.x + getWidth() / 2, pos.y + getHeight());//точка верхнего угла
    topleft = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y + getHeight() * .75f);//точка верхне-левого угла
    bottomleft = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y + getHeight() * .25f);//точка нижне-левого угла
    centr = new Vector2(pos.x + getWidth(),pos.y + getHeight());// точка сентра :)
    System.out.println("CREATE HEXGAON");
}

boolean enterHexagon(float x,float y) {
    boolean enter = false;
    boolean a,b,c,d,e,f;
    a = IsInTriangle(centr,bottom ,bottomright , x, x);
    b = IsInTriangle(centr, bottomright, topright, x, y);
    c = IsInTriangle(centr, topright, top, x, y);
    d = IsInTriangle(centr, top, topleft, x, y);
    e = IsInTriangle(centr, topleft, bottomleft, x, y);
    f= IsInTriangle(centr, bottomleft, bottom, x, y);
    if(a && b && c && d && e && f) {
        enter = true;
    }else {
        enter = false;
    }
    System.out.println("ENTER HEXGAON");
    return enter;
}
```

запихать вот в это

```
 addListener(new InputListener() {
    public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);

        }
    }


    public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {

        super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);

    }
});
```

или мне нужно переопределить это?

```
     public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    if (touchable && this.touchable != Touchable.enabled) return null;
    return x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height ? this : null;
}
```

или что то из этого ?

```
   public Vector2 screenToLocalCoordinates (Vector2 screenCoords) {
    Stage stage = this.stage;
    if (stage == null) return screenCoords;
    return stageToLocalCoordinates(stage.screenToStageCoordinates(screenCoords));
}

/** Transforms the specified point in the stage's coordinates to the actor's local coordinate system. */
public Vector2 stageToLocalCoordinates (Vector2 stageCoords) {
    if (parent != null) parent.stageToLocalCoordinates(stageCoords);
    parentToLocalCoordinates(stageCoords);
    return stageCoords;
}

/** Transforms the specified point in the actor's coordinates to be in the stage's coordinates.
 * @see Stage#toScreenCoordinates(Vector2, com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4) */
public Vector2 localToStageCoordinates (Vector2 localCoords) {
    return localToAscendantCoordinates(null, localCoords);
}

/** Transforms the specified point in the actor's coordinates to be in the parent's coordinates. */
public Vector2 localToParentCoordinates (Vector2 localCoords) {
    final float rotation = -this.rotation;
    final float scaleX = this.scaleX;
    final float scaleY = this.scaleY;
    final float x = this.x;
    final float y = this.y;
    if (rotation == 0) {
        if (scaleX == 1 && scaleY == 1) {
            localCoords.x += x;
            localCoords.y += y;
        } else {
            final float originX = this.originX;
            final float originY = this.originY;
            localCoords.x = (localCoords.x - originX) * scaleX + originX + x;
            localCoords.y = (localCoords.y - originY) * scaleY + originY + y;
        }
    } else {
        final float cos = (float)Math.cos(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        final float sin = (float)Math.sin(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        final float originX = this.originX;
        final float originY = this.originY;
        final float tox = (localCoords.x - originX) * scaleX;
        final float toy = (localCoords.y - originY) * scaleY;
        localCoords.x = (tox * cos + toy * sin) + originX + x;
        localCoords.y = (tox * -sin + toy * cos) + originY + y;
    }
    return localCoords;
}

/** Converts coordinates for this actor to those of a parent actor. The ascendant does not need to be a direct parent. */
public Vector2 localToAscendantCoordinates (Actor ascendant, Vector2 localCoords) {
    Actor actor = this;
    while (actor != null) {
        actor.localToParentCoordinates(localCoords);
        actor = actor.parent;
        if (actor == ascendant) break;
    }
    return localCoords;
}

/** Converts the coordinates given in the parent's coordinate system to this actor's coordinate system. */
public Vector2 parentToLocalCoordinates (Vector2 parentCoords) {
    final float rotation = this.rotation;
    final float scaleX = this.scaleX;
    final float scaleY = this.scaleY;
    final float childX = x;
    final float childY = y;
    if (rotation == 0) {
        if (scaleX == 1 && scaleY == 1) {
            parentCoords.x -= childX;
            parentCoords.y -= childY;
        } else {
            final float originX = this.originX;
            final float originY = this.originY;
            parentCoords.x = (parentCoords.x - childX - originX) / scaleX + originX;
            parentCoords.y = (parentCoords.y - childY - originY) / scaleY + originY;
        }
    } else {
        final float cos = (float)Math.cos(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        final float sin = (float)Math.sin(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        final float originX = this.originX;
        final float originY = this.originY;
        final float tox = parentCoords.x - childX - originX;
        final float toy = parentCoords.y - childY - originY;
        parentCoords.x = (tox * cos + toy * sin) / scaleX + originX;
        parentCoords.y = (tox * -sin + toy * cos) / scaleY + originY;
    }
    return parentCoords;
}
```

прошу прощение за странное и не совсем конструктивное изложение вопроса